# Split columns by occurence of first character

Tags: regex, visidata

I am trying to split a columns by an occurence of a first character in `visidata`. In short, from something like this:

```
some_filename:2019-05-24 12:00:01 Some logs
```

I want to create two columns:

```
some_filename        2019-05-24 12:00:01 Some logs
```

I've tried stuff below but to no avail:

```
:[1]
:\[1\]
:(1)
:\(1\)
:{1}
:\{1\}
```

Comment: What is the language? Maybe `^([^:]*)(?::(.*))?$` will do?

Comment: Seems this works: ```(.*?):(.*)``` It is supposed to be a regular regex

Comment: These two are almost the same, but `[^:]*`  is faster than `.*?`

Comment: just use ":",nothing more. column to go to split command and column as a separator.